# Swift - position items inside UIView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints

I am stuck in my project because I can not figure out how to constraint my items (`UILabel`, `UIImageView`, `UITableView`, ... ) inside a `UIView programmatically.

The thing is that my `UIView` `.transforms` by the click of a `button`. I know I could just let all the items appear like I did with my `UIView`. But that would mean that I had to animate each one of them and that seems not too smart..

That is my UIView (the gray background, -> the bottom bar can be ignored)

[image]

This is how I set up the `UIView`:

```swift
let wishlistView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    return v
}()
view.addSubview(wishlistView)

wishlistView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 140.0),
wishlistView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
wishlistView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30.0),
wishlistView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30.0),
```

Basically the question is how to constraint items inside of a `UIView` so I don't have to 'animate' each item. Instead I would only have to animate/transform my `UIView` and the rest of the items go along with it.

I hope my question is clear, I'm new here :) Couldn't find anything on that topic, appreciate any help!

Comment: Same way you add and constrain to begin with... `wishlistView.addSubview(aLabel)` followed by `aLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.topAnchor, constant: 12.0),` etc

Comment: but if I move my `UIView`, will the the item move along with it? Or would that cause an error?

Comment: You're right ! My problem was that I still had `view.addSubview(testLabel)` instead of `wishlistView.addSubview(testLabel)`. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give this a try:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let wishlistView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .darkGray
        v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        return v
    }()

    let aLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.text = "This is a Label"
        v.textAlignment = .center
        return v
    }()

    let theButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)
        v.backgroundColor = .blue
        return v
    }()

    var openConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var closedConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(theButton)

        view.addSubview(wishlistView)

        wishlistView.addSubview(aLabel)

        openConstraint = wishlistView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 140.0)
        closedConstraint = wishlistView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)

        openConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
        closedConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate ([

            theButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            theButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),

            openConstraint,
            closedConstraint,

            wishlistView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            wishlistView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30.0),
            wishlistView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30.0),

            aLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.topAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            aLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            aLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: wishlistView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),

        ])

        theButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showHideWishlist(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func showHideWishlist(_ sender: Any?) -> Void {
        if closedConstraint.priority == .defaultHigh {
            closedConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
            openConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
        } else {
            openConstraint.priority = .defaultLow
            closedConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
        }
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Tapping the "Tap Me" button will show / hide the "wishlistView":

[image]